# Return first five numbers form string within UDF

Tags: sql-server, replace, substring, user-defined-functions

I am working on `SQL Server` (2005,2008 & 2012)

I wanna extract first five numbers from varchar column via using `UDF`

**Input:**

```
rrr123ddd4567ddd19828www2
123hhhsss124ss18762s
qq12349wsss12376ss
```

**Output:**

```
19828
18762
12349
```

My Trail is as following:

```
DECLARE 
    @myString VARCHAR(1000),
    @temp VARCHAR(100),
    @position INT,
    @ExecuteInsert nvarchar (500),
    @FirstChar bit

SET @myString = 'rrr123ddd4567ddd19828www2'
SET @position = 1 
SET @FirstChar = 1
WHILE @position <= LEN(@myString)
BEGIN
 IF (ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@myString,@position,1))) = 1
     BEGIN
        SET @temp =  isnull(@temp,'') + SUBSTRING(@myString,@position,1)
        SET @FirstChar = 1
     END
 ELSE /* The char is alphabetical */
     BEGIN
     if (@FirstChar= 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @temp =  isnull(@temp,'') + ','
            SET @FirstChar = 0
        END
     END

SET @position = @position + 1
END 

IF (RIGHT(@temp,1) <> ',')
BEGIN
    SET @temp = @temp + ','
END


SELECT @temp = REPLACE(','+ @temp + ',',',,','')

SELECT @temp = Replace (@temp,',','''),(''') 

Select @temp = '(''' + @temp + ''')'
Create table #temp
(
    col1 varchar(100)
)
SET @ExecuteInsert = 'insert into #temp values ' + @temp

Execute sp_executesql @ExecuteInsert

select top 1 col1 from #temp
where LEN(col1) = 5
drop table #temp

-- Output >> 19828
```

The previous query is working well with string input , but I wanna using this code within `UDF` to could using it with columns.

if I used the previous query within UDF, the following error is raising:

> Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.

**EDIT**

if I used Table variable , I get the next error:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed
>   from within a function.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change the code to use a table variable rather than a temp table.

Comment: @R.Richards after changing it to table variable i get this error Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.GetFirstFiveNumbers", or the name is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here you are my answer of my question , hope helps others.*

The objective is creating `UDF` function for using it with columns, not only fixed values.

The approach is using [SplitString](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-and-convert-Comma-Separated-Delimited-String-to-Table-in-SQL-Server.aspx) instead of `sp_executesql`

for splitting a comma separated string and loop it's values in table.

**Demo:-**

```
Create table DummyTable
( col1 varchar (100))
go

Insert into DummyTable values ('rrr123ddd4567ddd19828www2')
Insert into DummyTable values ('123hhhsss124ss18762s')
Insert into DummyTable values ('qq12349wsss12376ss')

go

/*
    SplitString via Mudassar Khan
    http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-and-convert-Comma-Separated-Delimited-String-to-Table-in-SQL-Server.aspx
*/
Create FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------

/*
    My Own Function
*/

Create FUNCTION udfGetFirstFiveNumbers
(
@myString VARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
@temp VARCHAR(100),
@result Varchar (100),
@position INT,
@ExecuteInsert nvarchar (500),
@FirstChar bit

SET @position = 1 
SET @FirstChar = 1
WHILE @position <= LEN(@myString)
BEGIN
 IF (ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@myString,@position,1))) = 1
 BEGIN
SET @temp =  isnull(@temp,'') + SUBSTRING(@myString,@position,1)
SET @FirstChar = 1
END
ELSE /* The char is alphabetical */
BEGIN
if (@FirstChar= 1)
BEGIN
    SET @temp =  isnull(@temp,'') + ','
    SET @FirstChar = 0
END
END

SET @position = @position + 1
END 

IF (RIGHT(@temp,1) <> ',')
BEGIN
SET @temp = @temp + ','
END

SELECT @temp = REPLACE(','+ @temp + ',',',,','')

SELECT @result = Item
FROM dbo.SplitString(@temp, ',')
where len(Item) = 5

return @result
 END
 GO

--  Test

select col1, dbo.udfGetFirstFiveNumbers(col1) as result
from DummyTable
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfTest
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here

)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE
@Result int, 
@myString VARCHAR(1000),
@temp VARCHAR(100),
@position INT,
@ExecuteInsert nvarchar (500),
@FirstChar bit

SET @myString = 'rrr123ddd4567ddd19828www2'
SET @position = 1 
SET @FirstChar = 1
WHILE @position <= LEN(@myString)
BEGIN
 IF (ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@myString,@position,1))) = 1
 BEGIN
SET @temp =  isnull(@temp,'') + SUBSTRING(@myString,@position,1)
SET @FirstChar = 1
END
ELSE /* The char is alphabetical */
BEGIN
if (@FirstChar= 1)
BEGIN
    SET @temp =  isnull(@temp,'') + ','
    SET @FirstChar = 0
END
END

SET @position = @position + 1
END 

IF (RIGHT(@temp,1) <> ',')
BEGIN
SET @temp = @temp + ','
END

SELECT @temp = REPLACE(','+ @temp + ',',',,','')

SELECT @temp = Replace (@temp,',','''),(''') 

 Select @temp = '(''' + @temp + ''')'
 Declare @tempTable TABLE
 (
 col1 varchar(100)
 )

 insert into @tempTable SELECT @temp

 select top 1 @Result=col1 from @tempTable
 where LEN(col1) = 5
 return @Result
 END
 GO
```

Comment: How use table variable within inline function ?? .. I get the next error after returning table >>> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.GetFirstFiveNumbers", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: Please see this link http://sqlhints.com/tag/table-variables-in-user-defined-function/ for how to use table variable within user defined functions

Comment: it is not working , the main issue I wanna Return value from @tempTable, within inlined function how come ??

Comment: I get the next error: Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Comment: select top 1 @Result=col1 from @tempTable where LEN(col1) = 5

it is not working

Comment: Note: `ISNUMERIC` is a very poor way of parsing a string for numbers if the string isn't purely alphanumeric. e.g. `ISNUMERIC('-')`, `ISNUMERIC('+')` and `ISNUMERIC('$')` all evaluate to one. Better would be checking whether the substring is `LIKE '[0-9]'`.

Comment: @TonyDong . it is not working .. the end result is null, why ? becouse I MUST use  SET ExecuteInsert = N'insert into tempTable SELECT' + tem
 execute sp_executesql ExecuteInsert .. for inserting 4 rows